# Stealthiest Monster in DnD

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, stealth

We are a level 20 party about to embark on a stealth mission. My wizard has bad stealth so I’m trying to find the most undetectable creature I can find to polymorph into. By undetectable I mean high stealth, invisibility and teleportation abilities, entering the ethereal plane, just anything that lets me avoid detection in whatever way?

Comment: As a level 20 wizard, you have access to the *Etherealness* spell. Isn't sneaking around the kind of thing one such as you should leave to the Philistines? ;-)

Comment: There are a multitude of monsters up to CR 20, which have varying abilities which might be relevant. You need to narrow this down a lot. Creature size would be important, as well as any required abilities while polymorphed. Also please list allowed source material (books etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to pinpoint one monster that does all of these things well, but here's some exemplary suggestions of each.  (These suggestions assume that as a level 20 party, you're talking about *true polymorph* and thus aren't restricted to beasts).

### Invisibility

Hard to beat the [Invisible Stalker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/invisible-stalker) for this.  It's just... always invisible.  No concentration to maintain, nothing to dispel.  It just does that.  You could fly through an antimagic field and be just as invisible... if it didn't strip away your polymorph. Maybe pure invisibility doesn't do enough here.

### Planar Travel

Why not bring your friends with you?  Consider the [Nightmare](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/nightmare), which not only can swap between the material and ethereal at will, it can carry up to three creatures with it on each trip.

### Stealth

You don't need high CR to be hard to notice.  Check out the humble [chwinga](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chwinga).  You can cast *pass without a trace* at will, giving yourself a ridiculous +17 to stealth.  If you're traveling through an area with natural terrain, you can hide *inside* stones, trees, and water.  Nobody's catching you in there.  You'll also have 60 feet of blindsight to spot invisible guards with.  This is a solid choice to me as some of the chwinga's tools get around Truesight, a real threat at high levels.

Also nice since you can share *pass without a trace* with friends!

Note that using *pass without a trace* here will require you to permanently transform yourself into a chwinga so that you don't need to hold concentration.  Hopefully one of your friends has *dispel magic*.

### A healthy mix

Give the [Arcanaloth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/arcanaloth) a look.  At-will teleportation, at-will invisibility, at-will *alter self* (for the "Change appearance" mode).  *Mind blank* cuts out any divination spell.  Several castings of *dimension door* available if its natural teleportation isn't enough.  Note again that you'll need to lock yourself into being an arcanaloth for a while to take advantage of this, but it may be worth it, especially given that it's a strong spellcaster in its own right, with access to several offensive and defensive options if things go sideways.

I consider the only real weakness to this one to be *truesight*.

### So which to choose?

It's *highly* context dependent.  No option is going to be perfect, so you'll want to consider whether the information you have pushes you to put all your eggs in one basket, or to have a good chance against anything.  If you know for a fact that there's no Truesight or planar restrictions involved, just go nightmare and cruise through all the defenses along with the entire party.  If you expect a lot of varied resistance, perhaps an arcanaloth would be more appropriate.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: On your antimagic field comment regarding the Invisible Stalker, the Invisible Stalker's invisibility might not be affected, but your *true polymorph* spell will be.

Comment: Good point! I'll fix that.